# How to disable collision on a group of sprites while other groups remain enabled

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit

I have several  groups of `fly`sprites in each `flyGroup` please see my code below. I have given each flySprite the same Category name `flyCategory`.

```
struct FlyGroup    {
var flies : [Fly]
var isVisible = false
var isHighlighted = false

mutating func switchFliesON   ()  {
    for fly in flies  {
        fly.sprite.alpha = 1.0
        fly.sprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = flyCategory
    }
    isVisible = true
}

mutating func switchFliesOFF   ()  {
    for fly in flies  {
        fly.sprite.alpha = 0
        fly.sprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    }

    isVisible = false
}
}
```

thought that

```
fly.sprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
```

in

```
switchFliesOFF   ()
```

should disable the collisions between only flies in a given group, but it doesn’t. Please note that not all flyGroups are switched off at the same time. I thought of adding a name parameter to define specific categories for each group, but here is the case my groups increase to as many as 20, so managing so many groups becomes an issue.
Why isn’t

```
fly.sprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
```

disabling collisions? Also how can I disable collisions for all the fly sprites in one group only bearing in mind that some of the groups are visible (collisions are ON)?

Comment: Set both collision and category bit masks to zero on `fly.sprite.physicsBody` in `switchFliesOFF()` method, and in `switchFliesON()` set them back to their initial values.

Comment: @Whirlwind thanks, it's working